# Nginx encoding ? to %3F automatically when rewrite is applied

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

For incoming url: [http:/localhost:8080/gateway/redash/public/dashboards/uuid](https://stackoverflow.com) 
I am replacing /gateway/redash with empty and then need to lookup uuid in map to fetch url of the report.

***required final url:*** http://localhost:8080/public/dashboards/bnciuw749873dnSER498nc2i?org_slug=myorg

but due to rewrite rule the ***?*** is being encoded to ***%3F*** automatically, is there anyway to stop it from happening or retaining ***?*** as literal. hence ***?org_slug*** is not ***%3Forg_slug***

***error final url:*** http://localhost:8080/public/dashboards/bnciuw749873dnSER498nc2i%3Forg_slug=myorg

```
 map $request_uri $new_uri {
        default $request_uri;
        # UUID to Value mapping
        "/gateway/redash/public/dashboards/b12690b8-c5cb-4c7e-9d18-123456789" "/public/dashboards/bnciuw749873dnSER498nc2i?org_slug=myorg";
...
}


if ($request_uri ~ ^/gateway/redash/public/dashboards/) {
                rewrite ^/gateway/redash(/public/dashboards/[^/]+)$ $new_uri break;
            }
```

I tried replacing ? with a string called *QUERY_STRING* and then again replacing this with ?. But this is still resulting in same %3F encoding finally. Is there anyway to retain '?'.

Comment: Suggest you let `rewrite` add the `?` by using two maps. For example: `rewrite ^ $new_uri?$new_args? break;`